# Working DLL code fails with Run-time error 13: Type mismatch when debugging

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba, office-addins

This question is a stumper, for experts only.

We are using Visual Studio 6 to develop a complex COM Add-In for Access. When compiled, the Add-In works fine. But, when we use Ctrl-F5 to put the VB6 IDE in debug mode, Access throws a

> Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

error when it tries to assign the Access `Application.COMAddIns("AddInName").Object` reference to an early-bound VBA variable of a type exposed in the `AddInName` type library.

Further information:

- The Access application uses objects created by calls to the Add-In
- The Add-In DLL also serves as a type library that is included in Access VBA References
- The type Access requests from the Add-In is defined in the `AddInName` type library

In Access VBA, the failing code looks like this:

```
Public Function GetAddInRef As AddInName.SomeClass
    Dim objSomeClass As AddInName.SomeClass
    ' .Object is set to a SomeClass instance in IDTExtensibility2_OnConnection
    Set objSomeClass = Application.COMAddIns("AddInName").Object ' => Error 13!
    Set GetAddInRef = objSomeClass 
End Function
```

If you change the type of `objSomeClass` to `Object`, the assignment works. If you set a break on the offending line, you can do things like this in the Immediate window:

```
? TypeName(objSomeClass)
AddInName.SomeClass
? TypeOf objSomeClass Is AddInName.SomeClass
False
```

So it is saying that the class name of `objSomeClass` is "AddInName.SomeClass", but it is **not** of type `AddInName.SomeClass`. Madness!

Further, if you put in code that exposes the CLSID for the Access-side reference and the Add-In originated object, they both return the **same** GUID! So why does VBA complain that the types are different?

Does anyone have any insight into what is happening here? I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a colleague of mine stumbled upon the answer: Set Access and VB6 permissions to administrator! I tried it, and Voilà, debugging works.

For each of the following executable files, Right-click, Properties, Configuration, then check Run this program as an administrator:

1. Office path:

   ```
   MSACCESS.EXE (or EXCEL.EXE or WINWORD.EXE ...)
   ```
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\

   ```
   VB6.EXE
   LINK.EXE
   ```

Notes:

- It probably helps to develop VB6 apps using an administrative login, too.
- This makes sense, because VB6 had its start in the Windows 95 era, when users were pretty much the king of their OS instance.

**Caveat:** this may not be a perfect solution for very complex Access forms with lots of DLL interaction, but it is much better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (I am no expert) it's because AddInName.SomeClass is not an object, it is of type AddinName.SomeClass.  Drop the .Object off of Application.COMAddIns("AddInName").Object and I think it will work just fine.  If you need it as an object for somewhere else in your code, then change your AddInName.SomeClass types to Object and leave the .Object on Application.COMAddIns("AddInName").Object and it should work.

Comment: `AddInName.SomeClass` is indeed a type of object that I defined. I want to use this specific type, rather than a generic `Object` type, for compile-time validation of my code. The type of `Application.COMAddIns("AddInName"))` is `COMAddIn`. It has an .Object property which allows you to pass an object (which can be anything) back to the host application. Remember, this all works fine with a compiled DLL, so I'm pretty certain this code works. It fails when I try to debug.